# Using weeknum on date and time text results with #VALUE

Tags: excel, date

So my friend has this template he got from his boss, it's got a bunch of dates and times and other data. He told me he created a new workbook and copied everything from the template to this new workbook and then he modified the dates. The date and time listing he copied from another file.

So this is where the problem occurs, when he's done copying, one entire column resulted with #VALUE! instead of expected result w/c would be in yy/ww format. The formula is written below:

```
=MID(N2,9,2)&"/"&IF(LEN(WEEKNUM(N2,1))=1,"0"&(WEEKNUM(N2,1)),(WEEKNUM(N2,1)))
```

Inside N2 is `26/08/2014 1:27 PM`. So I googled a bit and found out that WEEKNUM doesn't work for text-style date and time. Should only work with serial numbers, if I understand it correct. I checked the N column (which was all copied from another file) and they were all in text. But when I checked the template, the dates were also all in text style. So how the formula worked with the template but not with the new workbook? (I'm assuming that every text in every cell is aligned to the left, dates in both new workbook and the template are both aligned to the left.)

I told my friend that the N column should be in date format so I suggested him this formula:

```
=(DATE(2014,8,26) + TIME(13,27,0))
```

And finally it worked. But his and my concern would be that we can no longer just copy and paste the dates but manually input every date within the formula. But there's just too many dates and it would take a long time to finish.
Any way around this?

UPDATE:
I just noticed something. The format of the dates copied is dd/mm/yyy h:mm AM/PM. When I checked on the column where all the `#VALUE!`s are spawning, there are exceptions. I actually found 3-4 cells that are normal.
The date is: `02/10/2014 3:49 PM` and the result with using the formula is `15/49`. I'm wondering, could it have been with how the dates are typed in? Or rather copied in? Like, should the date format be in mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy?

Used evaluate formula and it said that N2 contains a constant.

Comment: You've got a point there. I noticed that on a few cells that despite the text being copy pasted, the formula worked.
Well, according to properties, both are in English.

Comment: You mentioned "The date is: `02/10/2014 3:49 PM` and the result with using the formula is `15/49`". This can't be true if the text `02/10/2014 3:49 PM` is in column N. The Formula takes `MID(N2,9,2)`. Where should the `15` comes from? And week number 49 can neither be in October nor in February.

Comment: Just an aside but if you want leading zeroes for week numbers, assuming an actual date in N2 you can use this formula for your yy/ww =TEXT(N2,"yy")&"/"&TEXT(WEEKNUM(N2),"00")

Comment: @Axel, alright I noticed that. When I checked the worksheet, apparently, I was looking at a cell below the one I was supposed to look at. Sorry abut that. Answer's 14/35. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WEEKNUM` function works with dates as text while it can implicitly convert the text to date. Example:

Input `'31/03/2015`in A1 and `=WEEKNUM(A1)` in B1. Input `'03/31/2015` in A2 and `=WEEKNUM(A2)` in B2. Note the leading `'` before the dates. They will convert the inputs to text. One of them will work, one will not. This will indicate which is your default date format `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`.

You say both Excel are English but there is a difference in default date format between GB English and US English unfortunately.

So if the dates are text in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and your default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, you can't simply copy them into your Excel and work with them. You have to change them ever to `mm/dd/yyyy` first. Ever, because even the values which seems to work are mostly wrong. `WEEKNUM` with the text `09/11/2015` will work even with default date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. But it will implicitly convert the text to September 11. 2015 while with `dd/mm/yyyy` 09. November 2015 was meant.

Best solution ist not to use dates in text format. If your friend's boss had used date values instead of text then copy&paste would work. But because he had not, you have to convert the formats in a helper column now. Try

```
=MID(N2,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(N2,2)&"/"&MID(N2,7,999)
```

copied down in a helper column.

Comment: Yep, did just that. I told my friend to follow the date format of what's copied down on the worksheet. Changed the date format of his computer to follow on the worksheet's date format.